# GitLab SSH push fail out of memory malloc failed error

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, push

I'm trying to push a large .sql file of 1.4GB to a gitlab project through ssh. But the push fails with the following error : 
`Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1452837977 bytes)
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit`

Here is the content of my gitconfig file

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
url = my ssh url 
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Is there a liit on the size of objects on gitlab? I know that github does have a 100mb/object limit.

Comment: Yes there's a limit but I have set it to 100gb

Comment: I would use git-lfs. Large files in a Git repo usually lead to a lot of unhappiness later.

Answer (score 1):

First,Git does **not** allow file to be greater than 100 MB. So, there is really no chance for Gigabytes(OR it is bad to increase the max-size)!

Git does not allow it for a reason. Let us say you have a file of 1 GB. Every commit in git does not save the diff, instead it takes the entire snapshot of that file. So, eventually after 3 commits, your repo would be 3 GB in size and simply it kills your space and causes slowdowns in clone,fetch,and everything.

If you use git-lfs, the **pointer to the actual LFS tracked file is actually saved** in your repository. The 3 GB data is still present in your remote repository(as BLOB), but not all 3 GB data is saved on your local repository,Depending on your commit hash, git-lfs lazily downloads only the version you are currently on rather than having all three versions, thus you will have only 1 GB file irrespective of the commit you are working on.